# How to use orderBy for a property of an array of arrays in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to order the following example data set by the value property or a specific array index?:

```
var rows = [
    [
        {
            value: 'hello',
            label: 'world'
        },
        {
            value: 'hello1',
            label: 'world1'
        },
        {
            value: 'hello2',
            label: 'world2'
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            value: 'asd',
            label: 'jkl'
        },
        {
            value: 'asd1',
            label: 'jkl1'
        },
        {
            value: 'asd2',
            label: 'jkl2'
        }
    ]
];
```

I tried this repeat statement:

```
ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:'-[1].value'"
```

It's not throwing an error but it also doesn't do the ordering.

Comment: ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy: value"

Comment: This only works if "row" is an object, but it's an array.

Comment: Do you want to order rows or the values in each row?

Comment: Since, its a 2d array, you can try having nested ng-repeat and then orderBy: value in inner ng-repeat.

Comment: Imagine the data set represents a table and you want to order this table by the value of a specific column.

Comment: Have you tried  ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy: '[1].value' " (without the dash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ng-repeat this this. This will order rows by the values of first column. `this` represents the row.

```
ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:'this[0].value'"
```